# Frégier and Frégier's Theorem

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, euclidean-geometry

A curious and interesting gem is Frégier's theorem, quoted here from David Wells:

> Choose any point $P$ on a conic, and make it the vertex of a right
>   angle which rotates about $P$.  Then the lines through the points of
>   intersection, $AA$, $BB$, and so on, will all pass through a fixed
>   point $X$ which lies on the normal at $P$, that is, on the line
>   through $P$ perpendicular to the tangent at $P$.

Who was Frégier, and where can I find the earliest publication of his theorem?

Answer (score 3):

The theorem of [Frégier](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015038637651;view=1up;seq=421;skin=mobile) (Correspondance sur l'Ecole Royale Polytechnique tome III, p.394, 1816) is a limiting case of 144(a) (See footnote on p.324 of "An Introduction to the ancient and modern geometry of conics, being a geometrical treatise on the conic sections with a collection of problems and historical notes and prolegomena" by Taylor, Charles, 1840-1908).

For quick view of the above reference, scroll down to p.394, or use Contents and go to Section 11 for p.394.

Answer (score 2):

Frégier appears to have published the result in

> M. Frégier, Géométrie analitique. Théorèmes nouveaux sur les lignes et
> surfaces du second ordre. Annales de Mathématiques pures et appliquées,
> tome 6 (1815-1816), p. 229-241

Here's a [PDF](http://www.numdam.org/article/AMPA_1815-1816__6__229_0.pdf).

and what looks like the relevant theorem

[image]

The following article helped me track this down, via some citations in the introduction:

> LIPPS, KATHERINE SUE. “Envelopes of Certain Families of Conics.” Pi Mu
> Epsilon Journal, vol. 2, no. 8, 1958, pp. 359–363. JSTOR,
> [www.jstor.org/stable/24344939](http://www.jstor.org/stable/24344939). Accessed 27 June 2020.

For anybody who wants to access Gergonne's Annales, there is an index at http://www.numdam.org/item/AMPA/